# How to aggregate with multiple months with data frame R?

Tags: r, aggregate-functions

I need to aggregate multiple months from original data with dataframe in R, e.g: data frame with datetime include 2017 and 2018.

```
        date category       amt
  1 2017-08-05        A 0.1900707
  2 2017-08-06        B 0.2661277
  3 2017-08-07        c 0.4763196
  4 2017-08-08        A 0.5183718
  5 2017-08-09        B 0.3021019
  6 2017-08-10        c 0.3393616
```

What I want is to sum based on 6 month period and category:

```
         period category       sum
1 2017_secondPeriod        A 25.00972
2  2018_firstPeriod        A 25.59850
3 2017_secondPeriod        B 24.96924
4  2018_firstPeriod        B 24.79649
5 2017_secondPeriod        c 20.17096
6  2018_firstPeriod        c 27.01794
```

What I did:
    1. select  the last 6 months of 2017, like wise 2018
    2. add a new column for each subset to indicate the period 
    3. Combine 2 subset again
    4. aggregate
as following:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(
  date = today() + days(1:300),
  category = c("A","B","c"),
  amt = runif(300)
)

df2017_secondHalf <- subset(df, month(df$date) %in% c(7,8,9,10,11,12) & year(df$date) == 2017)
f2018_firstHalf <- subset(df, month(df$date) %in% c(1,2,3,4,5,6) & year(df$date) == 2018)

sum1 <- aggregate(df2017_secondHalf$amt, by=list(Category=df2017_secondHalf$Category), FUN=sum)
sum2 <- aggregate(df2018_firstHalf$amt, by=list(Category=df2018_secondHalf$Category), FUN=sum)

df2017_secondHalf$period <- '2017_secondPeriod'
df2018_firstHalf$period <- '2018_firstPeriod'

aggregate(x = df$amt, by = df[c("period", "category")], FUN = sum)
```

I try to figure out but did not know how to aggregate multple months e.g, 3 months, or 6 months.

Thanks in advance
Any suggesstion?

Comment: Note that the purported answer in the question does not correspond to the data you show. Please fix it so that your input and output correspond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a 3 line solution that uses no package. Let `k` be the number of months in a period.  For half year periods `k` is 6.  For quarter year periods `k` would be 3, etc.    Replace 02 in the `sprintf` format with 1 if you want one digit suffices (but not for monthly since those must be two digit).  Further modify the `sprintf` format if you want it to exactly match the question.

```
k <- 6
period <- with(as.POSIXlt(DF$date), sprintf("%d-%02d", year + 1900, (mon %/% k) + 1))
aggregate(amt ~ category + period, DF, sum)
```

giving:

```
  category  period       amt
1        A 2017-02 0.7084425
2        B 2017-02 0.5682296
3        c 2017-02 0.8156812
```

At the expense of using one package we can simplify the quarterly and monthly calculations by replacing the formula for `period` with one of these:

```
library(zoo)

# quarterly
period <- as.yearqtr(DF$date)

# monthly
period <- as.yearmon(DF$date)
```

**Note:** The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "date category       amt
  1 2017-08-05        A 0.1900707
  2 2017-08-06        B 0.2661277
  3 2017-08-07        c 0.4763196
  4 2017-08-08        A 0.5183718
  5 2017-08-09        B 0.3021019
  6 2017-08-10        c 0.3393616"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
DF$date <- as.Date(DF$date)
```

Comment: Thanks Grothendieck   but the result  is a bit different to what I got . Could you check with my generated data.

Comment: Try it again I had revised it at one point and you likely got the code prior to that. revision Also note that to get the answer I got you must use the data I used which is in the Note at the end of the answer and comes from the question.

Comment: Hi Grothendieck. I appreciate for your quick reply. I use the first three line of codes (df instead DF) to check with my result. I see in your solution CategoryB (24.62236, 27.46779) for 2017 and 2018 while my CategoryB  (24.96924, 24.79649) on the same data frame I generate.

Comment: The amounts for category B are 0.2661277 and 0.3021019 so their sum is 0.2661277 + 0.3021019 = 0.5682296 which is what I showed.  At any rate, my answer is reproducible -- just copy and paste the code in the Note and then the code in the answer

Comment: Perfect. Thanks G. Grothendieck

Answer (score 2):

With lubridate and tidyverse (dplyr & magrittr)

First, let's create groups with Semesters, Quarter, and "Trimonthly".

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- df %>% mutate(Semester = semester(date, with_year = TRUE),
                    Quarter = quarter(date, with_year = TRUE),
                    Trimonthly = round_date(date, unit = "3 months" ))
```

Lubridate's semester() breaks by semsters and gives you a 1 (Jan-Jun) or 2 (Jul-Aug); quarter() does a similar thing with quarters.
I add a third, the more basic round_date function, where you can specify your time frame in the form of size and time units. It yields the first date of such time frame. I deliberately name it "Trimonthly" so you can see how it compares to  quarter()

```
Pivot.Semester <- df %>% 
    group_by(Semester, category) %>% 
    summarise(Semester.sum = sum(amt))
Pivot.Quarter <- df %>% 
    group_by(Quarter, category) %>% 
    summarise(Quarter.sum = sum(amt))
Pivot.Trimonthly <- df %>%
    group_by(Trimonthly, category) %>%
    summarise(Trimonthly.sum = sum(amt))
Pivot.Semester
Pivot.Quarter
Pivot.Trimonthly
```

**Optional:** If you want to join the summarised data to the original DF.

```
df <- df %>% left_join(Pivot.Semester, by = c("category", "Semester")) %>% 
    left_join(Pivot.Quarter, by = c("category", "Quarter")) %>% 
    left_join(Pivot.Trimonthly, by = c("category", "Trimonthly"))
df
```

Comment: Thx Nicolas. It is amazing. but why after aggregating, the number of rows is the same before. Look at the result, I see there are aggregate for each date. Do you have any idea

Comment: Oh, I merged with the left_join() the values of the summarized tables (Pivot.Semester, Pivot.Quarter, Pivot.Trimonthly) into your original dataframe.

If you just want the summarised data, do not run the last instruction.

Comment: I could not  raise my vote but I want to give a thumb up